# Show the the image of correspondence is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $\Gamma : X \to Y$ is compact-valued and upper hemi continuous, then for any compact set $K\subseteq X$, the set $\Gamma(K) \subseteq Y$ is also compact. [ Hint: To show that $\Gamma(K)$ is bounded, suppose the contrary. Let $\{y_n\}$ be a divergent sequence in $\Gamma(K)$, and choose $\{x_n\}$ such that $y_n \in \Gamma(x_n)$, all $n$.] ($X, Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$)

In my book, the definition of u.h.c. is that for every $(x_n) \to x$ and every $(y_n)$ such that $y_n \in \Gamma(x_n)$, there exists a subsequence of $(y_n)$ converging to the limit in $\Gamma(x)$.

I can prove the closedness. For boundedness, following the hint, I first construct a divergent sequence $(y_n)$ such that $y_n \in \Gamma(x_n)$. Since $K$ is compact, there exists a subsequence $(x_n^*)$ of $(x_n)$ converging to $x \in K$. We als have a corresponding sequence $(y_n^*)$. Since $\Gamma$ is u.h.c, there exists a subsequence $(y_n^{**})$ of $(y_n^*)$ converging to $y \in \Gamma(x)$. I am stuck here because I don't know how to reach a contradiction from here. I would appreciate if you give some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. When the hint says to let $\{y_n\}$ be divergent, they want $\|y_n\| \to \infty$, not just $y_n$ not to converge converge. So, the convergent subsequence $y^{**}_n$ converging to some $y$ is indeed a contradiction, as it would suggest $\|y^{**}_n\|$ would have some finite limit.

Comment: But, divergent sequence does not necessarily imply that it has no convergent subsequence, right? for example $y_{2n} = n$ and $y_{2n+1} = 0$.

Comment: I'm saying, by "divergent", they don't mean "not convergent", they mean $\|y_n\| \to \infty$. You're right that "divergent" typically means "not convergent", but I think the hint was worded a little poorly. Note that you can assume $\|y\|_n \to \infty$ because you are assuming $T(K)$ is unbounded.